# Swift - Using Native Facebook Login Button with Parse Functionality

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to use the native Facebook login View `FBLoginView` for my Facebook Parse login, but the issue is that I am not sure how to associate a send action with the view and when I try to run the Parse Facebook login functionality through one of the native Facebook login functions, the actual login does not work correctly. The reason I know it isn't despite any errors is the fact that my `loginCancelledLabel` does not trigger when I click cancel.

Is there a way to associate the native way of creating the login button via `FBLoginView` to the Parse functionality, or will I have to create a button and use a Facebook login image that sends the Parse functionality on the click?

Here is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //Set Parse Application ID
        Parse.setApplicationId("xxxxx", clientKey:"xxxxx")

        //Initialize Facebook
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()


        return true
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
            return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication,
                withSession:PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())
    }
}
```

LoginViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    //Facebook login button view
    @IBOutlet var facebookLoginButton: FBLoginView!

    //User cancels login label
    @IBOutlet var loginCancelledLabel: UILabel!

    var permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Check to see if Parse user is already logged in
        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            println("User Logged In")
        } else {
            println("User Not Logged In")
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    //Function to call when Facebook login button view is selected
    func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {

        self.loginCancelledLabel.alpha = 0

        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                } else {
                    println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                }
            } else {
                println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                self.loginCancelledLabel.alpha = 1
            }
        })
    }
}
```